# 2 Servers 2 Different Companies

Tags: web-hosting, vps

Had major hosting company (HG) go down today, all servers,vps, hosting etc for 6hrs.

Question: I want to have two VPS machines. One with company A,   And one with company B.
I want to keep one website up using both vps machines with 2 different companies (different locations)..How do I set this up so if one goes down while the other "seamlessly" keeps the site running?

There was another question similar to this on stackoverflow but was not really answered.
[Can a website be hosted on 2 servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116367/can-a-website-be-hosted-on-2-servers)   Best answer so far was -1

Any other solutions?

Comment: Q sees not better here!

Answer (score 0):

DNS failover should do what you want. If you use reasonable short TTL for your CNAME or A/AAAA records.

You have to design the failover scenario:
* how the primary site failure is detected
* how the state of the web app is transfered to  the backup location
* how DNS records are changed
* how is the system restored back to primary site